# Color displays different in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, colors, cross-browser

I have an issue where color is shown differently in FireFox, compared to Chrome and IE. And i have no idea how come.
What would you do in my situation to get the same color displayed in all the browsers?
See http://www.inoplay.dk/
The top v-sign background is another blue (in FireFox), compared to the rest of the header, even though i selected exact same color in photoshop.
I have limited possibilities to edit the theme/template in PrestaShop, so simple CSS solution all i can do.

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if you put `background: linear-gradient(180deg, #DADADA 50%, #3D6CAD 50%);` in theme8.css (line 300)? http://oi58.tinypic.com/2870r5u.jpg

Comment: Thanks for input. I tried to do this, but then colors was different in all other browsers. I dont know if it's an issue with displaying colors for Chrome in Windows10 maybe. None the less i did changes to the theme files to make it work, inserting transparent images, so only 1 div background controls all the color in the header.

Comment: On Google Chrome 44 everything is ok. I'll check it again. Try to disable cache in your browser or use Ctrl+Shift+R. One of your images is missed: http://www.inoplay.dk/images/bx_loader.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that affect how these images render against HTML hex color codes.

1. It could vary whether or not each browser is using hardware acceleration which would affect how colors are rendered
2. The compression of the JPEG can sometimes cause color shifting
3. Make sure all your web images are in RGB color space/profile

SUGGESTION: the easiest way to get around this is to create your menu element as .PNG - PNG allows you to have a transparent background. This way you won't need to try to match the blue with code. It will just be transparent.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the image in jpg format. i hope it should solve the issue

Comment: That is working in FireFox. But i can see that in Google Chrome on Windows10, i am experiencing issues with color displaying aswell.